# Cannot display or echo alt text on featured image

Tags: php, loop, images

I seem to have a problem trying to display the "alternative text" of the featured image.

Here is the code that I have been working on. Not sure why the alternative text is showing blank.

```
        <?php 

        $projects = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'print-billboard' ) );
        if ( $projects->have_posts() ) : while ( $projects->have_posts() ) :
        $projects->the_post();



        ?>

            <?php 
            $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );
            $featured_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
            $alt = get_post_meta( $featured_image, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :

            ?>


            <a href="<?php echo $featured_image_url; ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'four columns project-post fancybox' ) ?> >

                <?php $thumbnail_meta = get_post_meta( $featured_image, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ); ?>

                <figure class="full-width featured-image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $featured_image[0]; ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" alt="<?php echo $featured_image; ?>" />
                    <div class="overlay">
                    </div>
                </figure>



            </a>

            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>

        <p class="error-message">No Projects</p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure of what I am going to say, but from a fast look, $featured_image is an array  **(URL, width, height, is_intermediate)**. so assuming that your alternative text exists in this array, you need to specify its index like this: 
**$featured_image[index_of_alt_text]**
according to my understanding, the $featured_image array doesn't contain your alternative text or you didn't specify the index.

I hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ( $projects->have_posts() ) : while ( $projects->have_posts() ) :
    $projects->the_post();

/*****     Thumbnail     ******/
    the_post_thumbnail(
        array(120, 90),     //Size of the thumbnail Image
        array(

            'class' => 'class_name',     //Specify class name to thumbnail image if any
            'alt' => 'post thumbnail',   // alternate text in case if no thumbnail image to show
            'title' => 'Notice'          //Specify title if want to
        )
    );
/*******     Thumbnail Ends   ********/
```